# Codeigniter Multiple Join Not Getting Sub Cat "Name" with Group_Concat

Tags: codeigniter

On my list below I have all my categories displayed, but the sub categories do not display name. The sub category names should display like

```
Example
Example > Some Example 1
Example > Some Example 2
PHP
PHP > Functions
```

> **Question:** On my model I should be able to retrieve the sub category name and the parent category name. But not working. Can only display parent name as shown in image I use group concat but it not show up in list group concat should display with > when sub cat name is there.
>
> Why is it not working and what is the best solution?

[image]

As shown on image not display the `> Some Example 1`.

On my model I am using multiple join tables and I use for example .c1 and .cd1 get's parent categories and .cd2 .c2 gets sub categories.

But when I use my db->select with Group Concat it does not work and only gets the parent category name.

```
public function get_categories() {
    $language_id = '1';

    $this->db->select('cp.category_id AS category_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.name SEPARATOR "&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;") as name');
    $this->db->from('category_path cp', 'LEFT');

    // Parent Cat
    $this->db->join('category c1', 'c1.category_id = cp.category_id', 'LEFT');

    // Sub Cat
    $this->db->join('category c2', 'c2.category_id = cp.path_id', 'LEFT'); 

    // Parent Cat
    $this->db->join('category_description cd1', 'cd1.category_id = cp.path_id', 'LEFT');

    // Sub Cat
    $this->db->join('category_description cd2', 'cd2.category_id = cp.category_id', 'LEFT');

    $this->db->group_by('cp.category_id');
    $this->db->order_by('name', 'ASC');
    $this->db->where('cd1.language_id', (int)$language_id);
    $this->db->where('cd2.language_id', (int)$language_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();

}
```

Tried with false below not worked same result

```
$this->db->select('cp.category_id AS category_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.name SEPARATOR "&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;") as name', false);
```

Var dump of results

```
array(5) { [0]=> array(2) { ["category_id"]=> string(2) "19" ["name"]=> string(7) "Example" } [1]=> array(2) { ["category_id"]=> string(2) "22" ["name"]=> string(7) "Example" } [2]=> array(2) { ["category_id"]=> string(2) "25" ["name"]=> string(7) "Example" } [3]=> array(2) { ["category_id"]=> string(2) "23" ["name"]=> string(3) "PHP" } [4]=> array(2) { ["category_id"]=> string(2) "24" ["name"]=> string(3) "PHP" } }
```

LAST QUERY

```
SELECT `cp`.`category_id` AS `category_id`, GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.name ORDER BY level SEPARATOR " > ") as name FROM `category_path` `cp` LEFT JOIN `category` `c1` ON `c1`.`category_id` = `cp`.`category_id` LEFT JOIN `category` `c2` ON `c2`.`category_id` = `cp`.`path_id` LEFT JOIN `category_description` `cd1` ON `cd1`.`category_id` = `cp`.`path_id` LEFT JOIN `category_description` `cd2` ON `cd2`.`category_id` = `cp`.`category_id` WHERE `cd1`.`language_id` = 1 AND `cd2`.`language_id` = 1 GROUP BY `cp`.`category_id` ORDER BY `name` ASC
```

**Category Table**

[image]

**Category Desc Table**

[image]

**Category Path Table**

[image]

Comment: you can not get direct array of category and subcategory. you need to use recursive function to do this.  i have the solution for this and it is wor for upto 'n' leval of hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who shared idea's to help.

I have found the cause of the issue is on my add category function.

When ever I create a category if it is a sub category in my category_path table

If sub category id is lets say 22 and parent id 19

Then on category_path table row should have two row should of inserted two rows like below.

```
category_id  path_id  level
22           19        0
22           22        1
```

For some reason on my model **add category function** it's not inserting the path id correct

Now I know what need to fix on model function.

[image]

Full Working Model

```
<?php

class Model_category extends CI_Model {

    public function add() {
        $data = array(
            'parent_id' => (int)$this->input->post('parent_id'),
            'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
            'date_edited' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now()),
            'date_added' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())
        );

        $this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'category', $data);

        $category_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        $data = array(
            'category_id' => (int)$category_id,
            'language_id' => (int)'1',
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'meta_title' => $this->input->post('meta_title'),
            'meta_description' => $this->input->post('meta_description'),
            'meta_keyword' => $this->input->post('meta_keyword'),
            'date_edited' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now()),
            'date_added' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())
        );

        $this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'category_description', $data);

        // MySQL Hierarchical Data Closure Table Pattern

        $level = 0;

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'category_path');
        $this->db->where('category_id', (int)$this->input->post('parent_id'));
        $this->db->order_by('level', 'ASC');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $result) {

            $data = array(
                'category_id' => (int)$category_id,
                'path_id' => (int)$result['path_id'],
                'level' => (int)$level,
            );

            $this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'category_path', $data);

            $level++;
        }

       // The problem was here was not adding category into model but now
       // All Fixed.

        $data = array(
            'category_id' => (int)$category_id,
            'path_id' => (int)$category_id,
            'level' => (int)$level
        );

        $this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'category_path', $data);

        if (isset($data['keyword'])) {
            $data = array(
                'category_id' => 'category_id=' . (int)$category_id,
                'keyword' => $this->input->post('keyword'),
                'date_edited' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now()),
                'date_added' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())
            );

            $this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'url_alias', $data);

            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . $this->db->dbprefix . "url_alias SET query = 'category_id=" . (int)$category_id . "', keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($data['keyword']) . "'");
        }

    }

    public function edit() {
    }


    public function get_categories($data = array()) {
        $language_id = '1';
        $this->db->select('cp.category_id AS category_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.name ORDER BY level SEPARATOR " > ") as name, c1.parent_id, c1.sort_order');
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'category_path cp', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join($this->db->dbprefix . 'category c1', 'cp.category_id = c1.category_id', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join($this->db->dbprefix . 'category c2', 'cp.path_id = c2.category_id', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join($this->db->dbprefix . 'category_description cd1', 'cp.path_id = cd1.category_id', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join($this->db->dbprefix . 'category_description cd2', 'cp.category_id = cd2.category_id', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->where('cd1.language_id', '1');
        $this->db->where('cd2.language_id', '1');
        $this->db->group_by('cp.category_id');
        $this->db->order_by('name', 'ASC');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();

        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$this->db->select("cp.category_id AS category_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.name ORDER BY cp.level SEPARATOR '&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;') AS name, c1.parent_id, c1.sort_order", FALSE);
```

`$this->db->select()` accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement.

Comment: try to print your executed query with `$this->db->last-query();`

Comment: I have updated my question with the `$this->db->last_query();`

Comment: Did you get the desired result when you run this query in mysql  ?